# winbind from samba 3.6.3 on Linux works but does not integrate with OS?

Tags: linux, samba, winbind, integrated-authentication

Successfully compiled and installed the latest version of samba.

Started winbindd and the following diagnostic commands work:

`wbinfo -p`, `wbinfo -c`, `net ads testjoin`, etc...

However! when using built-in Linux command like `id` or when using pam with `pam_winbind` module to login. They fail and there is nothing in the logs referring to winbind. What could be the issue?

e.g.
`[root ~]# wbinfo -i testuser

testuser:*:10708:1513:Test User:/home/domain.ad/testuser:/bin/bash`
but !
`[root ~]# id testuser

id: testuser: No such user`

Note: previous versions (samba 3.5.x) worked well on our systems so it's not bad domain or configuration.

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

`passwd:     files winbind

shadow:     files winbind

group:      files winbind

hosts:      files dns wins
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files

netmasks:   files

networks:   files

protocols:  files

rpc:        files

services:   files

netgroup:   nisplus

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus

aliases:    files nisplus`

Comment: forgot to mention that in `nsswitch.conf` there are: `winbind` entries in the right places (otherwise the previous vers of winbind wouldn't work)

Comment: Can you post the actual (non-comment) contents of nsswitch.conf?

Comment: What is your backend - OpenLDAP, AD? We've never had much success with winbind and ended up disabling it, and things seem to work OK.

Comment: @Andrew: we use Windows 2008 AD. If you disable it how can AD integration work? Note: it worked for us with previous version of samba package, but its very old now with listed vulnerabilities

Comment: @larsks: edited the question, pasted nsswitch conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

just had to run `net cache flush` and then restart winbind